# Which debconf preseed option to auto reboot after installation?

Tags: preseed, debconf

Another pressed config to find here .. auto reboot after installation

[image]

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`d-i finish-install/reboot_in_progress note`

Alternately, to halt instead of reboot:

`d-i debian-installer/exit/halt boolean true`

To shutdown instead:

`d-i debian-installer/exit/poweroff boolean true`

Comment: Is there a complete reference to these variables anywhere?

Comment: Yes: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/209482/where-can-i-find-an-index-of-preseed-options . My preferred answer was debconf-get-selections --installer

Comment: Debian preseed configuration has bad documentation. To find syntax like this you need to have professional skill to find scattered information on the internet.

Answer (score 2):

```
# Avoid that last message about the install being complete.
d-i finish-install/reboot_in_progress note
```